# DirectionsRenderer - draw line to point outside road

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing directions using Google Maps API v3 DirectionsRenderer.
When start/end location is outside the road it is shown like this:
[image: Point outside the road]

I want to draw a line connecting the point on the road with exact location.
Something like this:
[image: Dotted line to exact location]

Is it possible to do this using Google Maps API v3?

Documentation does not say anything about this option. 
developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to draw a line connecting the point on the road with exact location". You have to draw that line as polyline. There is also the possibility to show the line as dotted line. Have a look at the look at the gmap examples (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex)